# Django form: formatting data from an instance before render

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.11, one of my models is an array stored within a [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield) field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    core = JSONField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

I am using a `ModelForm` in a couple of views to create and edit new instances. Within the ModelForm I'm borrowing the `django.contrib.postgres.forms.SimpleArrayField` to parse the input into the field.

Adding a new model is fine, but in the edit version, the array gets pre-populated with what looks like the `__str__` representation (eg an array of `1,2,3` becomes `['1','2','3']`.

I'm getting around this by parsing the array into `initial=` for each form but I'd rather do this in one place (DRY) rather than having to repeat it inside each view and form instance.

Are there any hooks or methods (perhaps a custom widget?) that means I can do this just once in the form or somewhere else?

Snippet of the current view with hacky approach using `initial=`:

```
def edit_mymodel(id):
    current_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = MyModelForm(instance=current_instance,
                           initial={"core": ",".join(current_instance.core)}
                           )
        return render(request, 'network_manager/edit.html',
                      {'form': form}
                      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `__init__`

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['core'] = ",".join(self.instance.core)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better place for the logic to live.